# Facebook tab application - application controlled icons / tab translations?

Tags: facebook, tabs

Is it possible to control a tab icon?

1. over tab settings?
2. over an API?

Why I'm asking: I'm trying to implement top company information into tabs. It's just one application. I can manually change the icon if I create a new application for each tab.
Is it possible to create one application that controls loaded iframe URL and change the icon from tab settings?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. Have a look at the *tabs* section in the [`page`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs) document, you can only update three parameters: `position`, `custom_name` and `is_non_connection_landing_tab`